# admob advanced filtering of ads (managing filters)

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have few admob sites and for each of them I want to set different filer for the content of the banners.
I want to do some manipulation with admob filter, unfortunately I do not even know the basics.

1. I want to show ads that contain image and no text (ads with image only)
   How to do this ?
2. I want to show ads that look like this (no phone)
   [image]
3. I want to show ads that have phones like this
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

For #1, if you disable AdSense backfill you can get rid of a lot of these text ads.  The AdMob network itself is not guaranteed to only have image ads though, so it doesn't fully solve this problem.  In addition, the fill rate on your ad slot would be much lower if you disable backfill, so this is generally not recommended.

For #2 and #3, the AdMob filters that are in place are ad category filters and language filters.  As far as I know, there is not support for ad type filters.